# WP8.1: Start an animation from the current location

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I want a control to change its position based on another property, but animate to that new position. However, whenever I start the new animation, the storyboard resets the control's position to the property set in the XAML.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);

// This gets the value that was set in the XAML, not the current value         
// animation.From = Canvas.GetLeft(BackgroundImage);
animation.To = newLocation;

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, BackgroundImage);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(Canvas.Left)");

Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
story.Children.Add(animation);
story.Begin();
```

Is there any way to either get the current animating value from the control to set as the animation.From, or is there a way to tell a Storyboard to start from the current property's location?

Answer (score 1):

Say if you want to animate the `Canvas.Left` property, the `From` value is indeed

```
Canvas.GetLeft(BackgroundImage)
```

However, by leaving the `From` property unspecified (like how you commented it out), the `Storyboard` should start from the current position. So you don't really need the code above.

Your animation looks fine to me. It could be something else that causes the problem.

---

**Update**

Here's a working example where a control gets animated to corresponding positions whenever a property is changed.

In my xaml, I created a `Slider` control and every time the `Value` of the `Slider` is changed, I want to animate the `Canvas.Left` of my `BackgroundImage` control to this `Value`. It's kind of acting like the **another property** you mentioned in your question.

**The Xaml**

```
<Slider x:Name="MySlider" Margin="12,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Minimum="20" Maximum="220" SmallChange="10" Value="20" />
```

**The Code**

```
private Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();
private DoubleAnimation _animation = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1) };

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Storyboard.SetTarget(_animation, this.BackgroundImage);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_animation, "(Canvas.Left)");
    _storyboard.Children.Add(_animation);

    this.MySlider.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        _animation.To = this.MySlider.Value;
        _storyboard.Begin();
    };
}
```

As you can see, I have kept two local variables for both the `Storyboard` and the `DoubleAnimation` instance. Then when the `ValueChanged` is called, simply set the `To` and kick off the animation.

Comment: When I've been testing, Canvas.GetLeft always returns the value set in the XAML, not the current value set from the storyboard. If I start a new storyboard, it always resets the Left value to what's set in the XAML.